# Is there a way to have HTML/JSP in a Java Method?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am making a program for my Advanced Java class, and I am wondering if doing something similar to this is valid. Right now, it is at the point where it looks like it might work, but it doesn't work because of the jsp:forward code segments.

```
<%!
    public void recurse() {
    QuestionSet qSet = (QuestionSet)session.getAttribute("questionset");
    String reqType = request.getParameter("reqType");
    if (condition1) {
  %>
      <jsp:forward page="questionform.jsp"/>
  <%
  } else if (condition2) {
  %>
      <jsp:forward page="answer.jsp">
          <jsp:param name="submitTime"
                     value="<%=(new java.util.Date()).toString()%>" />
      </jsp:forward>
  <%
    }

    String askQuestion = request.getParameter("askQuestion");
    if(askQuestion != null) {
      recurse();
    }
  }
  %>
```

Begin Edit:
After looking over this, I have reverted back to my working code. It works one time, but when I ask the user if they want to 'ask a question', it doesn't go through these if statements again:

```
  <%
    QuestionSet qSet = (QuestionSet)session.getAttribute("questionset");
    String reqType = request.getParameter("reqType");
    String askQuestion = request.getParameter("askQuestion");
    if (condition1) {
  %>
      <jsp:forward page="questionform.jsp"/>
  <%
  } else if (condition2) {
  %>
      <jsp:forward page="answer.jsp">
          <jsp:param name="submitTime"
                     value="<%=(new java.util.Date()).toString()%>" />
      </jsp:forward>
  <%
    }

    if(askQuestion != null) { //---HERE
      //Do it all again.
    }
  %>
```

How am I able to go through these if statements again and add to my QuestionSet list?

Comment: you should avoid having java code in jsp files. But, yes, you can write html from within a java file (servlet)

Comment: You can include content of jsp file in servlet response output stream by call `request.getRequestDispatcher(jspPageNameOrPath).include(request, response);` in servlet `doGet()` or `doPost()` methods.

Comment: I read the same thing, but for some reason this is what I am being taught. The lectures are from 2013… Thanks for the help!

Comment: Now I am getting `request cannot be resolved`, and same for response.